# Reverse Poincare inequality for Laplacian operator

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $\Omega$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $w \in H^2(\Omega)$. Does any one know some kinds of following inequality:

$\int_{\Omega}|\Delta w|^2 \leq c \int_{\Omega}|\nabla w|^2$

Comment: usually such inequalities are established for a given subset of $H^2$ only, which is often characterized as solutions for some kind of PDE, in this case presumedly a second order elliptic PDE.

Comment: can you give me some references for that? paper or book, etc..

Comment: sorry, that's just based on experience. plug in your equation to eliminate the second order terms and then start estimating (i.e. start with the LHS). The process in detail strongly depends on the type of your equation. Of course linear is always easiest. Also, dont forget about the boundary conditions.